Why do I see a very low count of URLs in Core Web Vitals section of Google Search console?
For Mobile, only ~2.6k URLs are shown across Good, poor and needs improvement whereas approximately 3L URLs are indexed by Google for my website

URLs which are indexed and are present in sitemaps

What can be the possible reason for this discrepancy and what steps can be taken to resolve this?

Google Search Console it's making many changes on their side. For what I read Core Web Vitals it's going to disappear from Search Console in the following weeks or months. Hopefully they come up with another metric, but as for now, we have this issue in many other websites.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
